# How to redirect to a certain page after submitting a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I have a form when you submit it  , it will send your inserted data  as an email to someone . Then the page redirects you to the Home page .

What I want is to prevent the redirection that the server side does. and I need to be able to choose where to redirect after submitting the form not the server side .

So what I did  , I used Javascript to prevent the redirection then i determined where to go after submitting .

Here's the form

```js
 $("#CustomerEnquiryForm").submit(function (e)
   {
        e.preventDefault();
        
        // My redirection //
        if (window.location.href.indexOf("nodeId") > -1)
        {
            window.location = "/en/our-service/"
        }
        else
        {
            window.location = "/en/"
        }

           
    });
```

```html
<form id="CustomerEnquiryForm" action="https://test.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST">
  
  
  
  
    <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
    <input id="first_name" required="required" name="first_name"  type="text" />
     <br>


    <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
    <input id="last_name" required="required"  name="last_name"  type="text" />
    
    <br>

    <label for="company">Company</label>
    <input id="company" required="required"  name="company"  type="text" /><br>

    <label for="phone">Phone</label><input id="phone"  name="phone"  type="text" />
    <br>

     <label for="mobile">Mobile</label>
     <input id="mobile" required="required"  name="mobile"  type="text" />
     <br>

     <label for="email">Email</label>
     <input id="email" required="required"  name="email" type="text" /><br>





  </form>
```

I could prevent the server redirection . and my redirection works .. but the main issue .. the form doesn't send emails anymore .

How to solve this issue ?

Thanks .

Comment: typically it is done by the script that gets the form data (in your case `https://test.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8`), you just put redirection code in there

Comment: Is the page that has this form on same `test.salesforce.com` ?

Comment: Use an hidden iframe or ajax to submit form

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
$("#CustomerEnquiryForm").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post("https://test.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8", $(this).serialize() , function(data, status) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(status);
        var obj = JSON.parse(data);
        //Read the server response here
        // My redirection //
        if (window.location.href.indexOf("nodeId") > -1) {
            window.location = "/en/our-service/"
        } else {
            window.location = "/en/"
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="CustomerEnquiryForm">
   <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
   <input id="first_name" required="required" name="first_name"  type="text" />
   <br>
   <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
   <input id="last_name" required="required"  name="last_name"  type="text" />
   <br>
   <label for="company">Company</label>
   <input id="company" required="required"  name="company"  type="text" /><br>
   <label for="phone">Phone</label><input id="phone"  name="phone"  type="text" />
   <br>
   <label for="mobile">Mobile</label>
   <input id="mobile" required="required"  name="mobile"  type="text" />
   <br>
   <label for="email">Email</label>
   <input id="email" required="required"  name="email" type="text" /><br>
   <button type = "submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Use `serialize()` not `serializeArray()` to replicate data sent using default form submit

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery for sending the form thru AJAX. 
With it, instead of submitting the page and redirecting to the submitted URL, you can send the data in the background, take the response and do redirection accordingly.

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,  //url where you want to send the data
  data: data, //somehow bind the input data to the variables and pass it
  success: someFunction, //you will get the response from server in this function
  dataType: 'JSON'
});
```

You can know more about AJAX [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Another option is to send the response in the link of your home URL, something like this

```
https://example.com/?red=somelink.com
```

and then redirecting it from the client side using javascript.

Answer (score -1):

> I could prevent the server redirection . and my redirection works .. but the main issue .. the form doesn't send emails anymore .

you need to manually send the data with ajax.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

```
// after e.preventDefault()
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest ;
xhr.open("POST","https://test.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8")
const formData = new FormData(document.getElemetById('CustomerEnquiryForm'))
xhr.send(formData)
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if( xhr.readyState === xhr.DONE && xhr.status === 200){
       // read server response
       console.log(xhr.reponseText)
       // redirect here
    }
}
```

or do the redirection serverside if you control the server.